# Get number of open orders for a symbol using Binance's Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, binance

I am using Binance's [Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-binance-api) API. It says regarding "Get open orders for a symbol", I should do:

```
binance.openOrders("ETHBTC", (error, openOrders, symbol) => {
  console.info("openOrders("+symbol+")", openOrders);
});
```

To print out number of open orders, I do:

```
binance.openOrders("ETHBTC", (error, openOrders, symbol) => {
  console.info(openOrders.length);
});
```

which works and the number gets printed out. However, I would need this result to be stored in a variable which  can be used later by other functions. Building on [SO's Javascript chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), I do:

```
let OO =
(async() => {
  const openOrders = await binance.openOrders(false);
  return openOrders.length
})()
console.log(OO)
```

This however prints

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

only.

I have seen several other questions discussing `Promise { <pending> }` issue but I haven't been able to implement their solutions to this specific case.

How could I get number of open orders into a variable accessible by other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use either completely async approach or use callbacks.

The last block in your question shows exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523970/1693192) explains. Javascript doesn't wait for `Promise` to resolve/reject in a synchronous context. So your "async" block returned the unresolved `Promise` and the rest of your (synchronous) code didn't wait for it to resolve.

Example of using async functions

```
const getOpenOrdersCount = async () => {
    const openOrders = await binance.openOrders("ETHBTC");
    return openOrders.length;
};

const run = async () => {
    const openOrdersCount = await getOpenOrdersCount();
    console.log(openOrdersCount);
}
```

*Note: You can use `await` only within `async` functions.*

Example of using callbacks is your code. They are useful in a small scope, but in bigger scope they get messy and turn into a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). So I wouldn't recommend using callbacks in a bigger scope.

```
binance.openOrders("ETHBTC", (error, openOrders, symbol) => {
  console.info(openOrders.length);

  // here goes rest of your code that needs to use the `openOrders` variable
});
```