# how to get [chrome.instanceID.getID] , [chrome.storage.sync.get] by async & await?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, async-await, es6-promise, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How do you get the information for the Chrome extension by using async and await?

```
[chrome.instanceID.getID]
[chrome.storage.sync.get]
```

We tried this code:

```
async function test()
{
let _r = await chrome.instanceID.getID();
return _r;
}
let _pc_id = test();
```

but `_pc_id` returns a promise. We find no way to get the value in it. How should we do this?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet :(  My Solution temporary is : creating a ID-byTiming once in 'chrome.runtime.onInstalled' as the Device Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instanceID like this, but can't store it in a variable to use it out of scope of the promise, AFAIK. You may want to read this: [saving data from promise in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569355/11324969)

If you want to use the returned value of Promise you need to do it in the promise or in `.then()`s after the promise, at least that is how I do it.

`chrome.instanceID.getID` example:

```js
chrome.instanceID.getID((instance_id) => {
    console.log(instance_id);
    // Execute your other related code here
});
```

or

```js
var promise = chrome.instanceID.getID();
promise.then((instance_id) => {
    console.log(instance_id);
    // Execute your other related code here
});
```

or

```js
chrome.instanceID.getID()
.then((instance_id) => {
    console.log(instance_id);
    // Execute your other related code here
});
```

`chrome.storage.sync.get` example:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get('myKey', function(items) {
    var key = items.myKey;
    // Below code is an example, change it to your needs
    if (key) {
        console.log(key)
    } else {
        key = createKey();    // a custom function that generates keys
        chrome.storage.sync.set({myKey: key}, function () {
            console.log(key);
        });
    }
};
```